# Can 'this' be undefined from within a prototype function?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is it possible for this prototype function to return false or is it a pointless check that will always return true?

```
if (!Date.prototype.hasOwnProperty("foo")) {
    Date.prototype.foo = function () {
        var date = this;
        if (!date) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you expect `this` to be `Date` object or just checking if function get some sort of `this`? (you can get `window` as `this` very easy...)

Comment: conditionally assigning a prototype (although possible) might be oddly complex. You you absolutely sure you need to conditionally assign to a prototype like that?

Comment: It's just a piece of code at the top of a prototype I'm looking at... just wondering if I could remove it, as I couldn't think of a way it could be hit. Is there a way that `this` could not be the calling variable, eg. for `var date = new Date(); date.foo();`?

Comment: Here is the prototype function: http://jsfiddle.net/dtYQc/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `this` keyword in JavaScript is only `undefined` if [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) is enabled. Otherwise, it will reference the `window` object by default, *unless* any of the following are true:

- The function is called using the `new` operator
- A different object is bound to `this` using `call()` or `apply()`

Comment: +1: Links to documentation [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)/[apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fapply) ": if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced with the global object".

Comment: So by this, the only way that this could happen is if I was under strict mode, and called `Date.prototype.foo.call(undefined)` or `.apply(undefined)`?